# Garland control circuit broke down

Tags: led, analog, led-driver

The garland is 220 V and consists of two series of 96 LEDs each. The LEDs are warm white, medium brightness, the current is unknown, perhaps about 20 mA. It will be enough to have a circuit without a transformer and without flickering. Can you recommend suitable options? I don't understand much analog electronics, but I can assemble some circuits.

There is no reference and characteristics, this is a Chinese product. The AC-DC controller is unknown and burned out completely.
I found one scheme for a garland. But it is designed for 24 LEDs of 50 ma, and I do not know what kind of pulsations it has. How can this circuit be adapted to 20 mA and without pulsations?
[image]
https://www.circuitstoday.com/mains-operated-led-circuit

And the second
[image]

https://crcit.net/c/68fc57a2bb544de9a7292a79032f2c5d

Comment: We need more details.  A link to the product you're talking about, what exactly "broke down" and what exactly you're trying to do about it.  "A circuit without a transformer" isn't very descriptive and may not be safe.

Comment: please ask a focused, answerable question ... asking for recommendations is off topic here, because that is asking for opinions

Comment: I have updated the request.